# Will there be an IAP callback for redeeming a promo code to exchange for a non-consumable product in iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, promotion-code

My problem is, the users cannot get the non-consumable item by redeeming the code.

I can confirm the non-consumable items can be bought correctly. 
I used the app receipt to check whether the user owns it. I'll find through all the products to see if there's one the product id is matching.

I cannot find any useful docs to debug the redeeming process. I don't even know if there should be a callback when the app starts. Like the transactions are not completed.

How is redeeming handled behind the scene?

If the app is open after I redeemed a code, how should the app know the user 'bought' the item? How should I know when to send them the contents?

If the users try to buy the item they redeemed, they are told they can get it for free, and I see the purchase succeed callback. But then I check app receipt, the product still not exists. I got these logs from the users.

By the way I'm using in_app_purchase plugin from Flutter. And for checking the app receipt I'm using https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore.

Answer (score 0):

Products redeemed with a promo code will appear on the receipt just as a purchased product would - you won't be able to differentiate from the receipt a purchase vs promo code.

There isn't a callback on the device for promos specifically, if you refresh the receipt or the user restores transactions you should see the product in the receipt.

Comment: I expect it the same way as you said, I tried to refresh the receipt but it's not in the app receipt for some apple ids (The issued one is from US app store). I tried to delete the app and redownload it again, but with no help. Is that a bug? Currently, I have to ask the user to purchase the same item in the shop, so that there's a callback for it and I can send them the item. The bad thing is I cannot check with the app receipt, but to store the complete status locally which is not safe enough. And it's still not good to ask the user to "pay" for it again.

Comment: I've actually heard of some users reporting the same thing (promo product not appearing in receipt). Could be an Apple bug. I saw on another forum that someone thought this was caused by redeeming a promo code with a Testflight build instead of a production build.

Comment: Would love to hear any updates on this.  I'm having a similar issue.  I have a non-recurring subscription IAP.  Redeeming a promo code for the IAP in the App Store doesn't ever appear in the receipt.  I'm struggling a bit with debugging this between production App Store promo codes and the debug sandbox.  Interesting to hear that others are having similar issues.